# Different version of same Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am porting a mobile app (native iOS, native Android) to Xamarin.Forms in order to share as much code as possible, including the UI which is quite simple.

My app is actually a template for every client. Every client will have their own customized app, running the same code, only the colors/images will change.
To achieve this on iOS, I would just create a new target and associate corresponding resources (color code files and images) to it.

How would I customize my app with Xamarin? I'm just starting to learn xamarin and could not find anything on that topic. Would it be easier without Forms?

--Edit

I realized there were 2 parts to solving my problem. I now know how to use app resources to organize the files thanks to this link:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_resources/
That's the first part.

But I still wonder what is the best to way to access the resources without changing the code. For example in iOS, every target can retrieve resources from the appropriate location by using the bundle name in the path. Is there an equivalent to adding a target?

Comment: There does not seem to have an equivalent to add a target(ios)/multi flavor(android), the closest workaround is to create a new project.
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45970/multi-flavors-android-target-ios-in-xamarin

Answer (score 1):

**Native**

Xamarin.Forms under hood is just a Xamarin.Android / Xamarin.iOS app. You can customize it with MainActivity class (Android) or AppDelegate class (iOS) before Xamarin.Forms is initialized (themes, colors, etc). You could define custom themes for app, just the same as native Android and set UI accent colors just the same as native iOS.

**Resources**

Resources in Xamarin.Fonts are just the same as native iOS / Android resources. So it's just the same approach. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/

**Styles**

Using styles for theme colors would be probably useful for you: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/

Answer (score 0):

You can have app-wide resources in Xamarin.Forms. Here's an example of how that would look in your App.xaml file:

```
<Application
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  x:Class="WorkingWithAppResources.App">
    <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
      </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Check out the [Working With Styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/) document for Xamarin.Forms. Specifically, the [application-wide resources](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/#Using_Xaml_for_your_App) section.